# Fixing Broken Kerberos on macOS

Tags: macos, kerberos, macos-high-sierra, osx-server

I've got a `macOS` 10.13 server running, on which I have recently had to change the `hostname` (upstream IT requirements) - and I suspect this has broken `Kerberos`.

Changing the `hostname` appears to have been successful: I exported the Open Directory setup, modified it, and `reimported` it into the updated setup - user accounts exist, and manual authentication works as expected. `changeip` is happy:

```
mac-mini:~ server_admin$ sudo changeip -checkhostname
dirserv:success = "success"
```

However SSO from client machines does not appear to be successful.

Attempting to run `kinit` with a valid user account shows this:

```
mac-mini:~ server_admin$ kinit test@MAC-MINI.EXAMPLE.COM
test@MAC-MINI.EXAMPLE.COM's password: 
kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: Server (krbtgt/MAC-MINI.EXAMPLE.COM@MAC-MINI.EXAMPLE.COM) unknown
```

Looking at `/etc/krb5.conf`, I only see this:

```
[libdefaults]
kdc_timeout=5
```

...which is the same as it was on my previously-working configuration.

And now I'm a bit stumped. All the documentation for destroying and rebuilding `Kerberos` setups seem to be out of date. Any ideas?!

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried restarting your client machine?

Comment: Hi - yes I have, but with no improvement. To be honest, I'm now moving to Active Directory as my KDC - so I'm dropping this line of enquiry.